# ngbtypeahead function returns TypeError when input is null

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I am using the typeahead element from ng-bootstrap in an Angular 8 project, https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples. I am using a function given in the examples of the library but if my one of the inputs is null i get an error.

I have a variable in my component class which is built with a function:

```
searchAutofill = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(200),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      map(term => term.length < 1 ? []
        : this.option.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1).slice(0, 15))
    )
```

option is an array of strings, for example:

```
[
    "tom",
    "bob",
    "foo",
    "emma",
    null,
    "john",
    "hello",
    "example",
```

When the function reaches the null value it returns `ERROR TypeError: "v is null"`. How can I change my code to accept/ignore null values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because you try to execute String method on 'null' value.

So here `v.toLowerCase()` you get `null.toLowerCase()`.

Whenever you access any property or method of an Object, you must be sure that that object is the object you expect. Otherwise set some rules to check that,

And in your case seems you want to check if string `v` has a substring in it saved in a `term` variable.

So my guess that you want to return `false` if `v` is `null`:

```
filter(v => v && v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1)
```

p.s. note that here I just check if `v` is not a falsy value. You might want to add additional rules to check if it is a string. Eg:

```
typeof v === 'string'
```

Comment: This works thank you. Does this mean "first check if v is not a falsy value" and then "execute .toLowerCare() and such"?

Comment: Yes. `&&` is a logical operator. In `bar && foo` - if bar is false, it will return false and wont even execute foo, so `foo.toLowerCase()` will not be called